# To install Devstack, how much memory should I use?

Tags: virtualbox, openstack, devstack

I installed VirtualBox and I want to install Devstack on ubuntu 14.10, this is **just for test**, So how much should I specify the RAM memory and Memory to use by the VM?

```
I have a windows 7 with 32 bits
Intel i3
RAM: 4 Go (2.64 Go usable)
27 Go space left on my disk
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing for testing, these are recommended settings for VM.

> - Processor - at least 2 cores
> - Memory - at least 8GB
> - Hard Drive - at    least 60GB

and Use at least **1 GB of RAM** but I would suggest to use **2GB RAM** to perform well.

Reference: [Setup DevStack](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/sahara/devref/devstack.html#start-vm-and-set-up-os)

Comment: Thank's for the reply, but if I assign  2 Go of RAM to my VM, that leave the host (windows) with only 0.64 Go of RAM i(f I'm correct) is it ok?

Comment: ok thanks new to all of this :) and what about the disk memory 20 Go should be fine

Answer (score 0):

See to it that you provide 2 cores and a minimum of 2  GB RAM. Devstack really needs a lot of CPU and still with this 2GB it will crouch a lot.
But basic configurations can still be done with this minimal settings.